# initial fetch with NSFetchedResultsController always returns empty objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsfetchrequest

The code below didn't return any objects on initial fetch, while succeeding fetch returns the right objects. I'm also checking the `vehicleManagedObjectContext`, but it is always empty.

```
    - (NSArray *)getVehicleInfo  {
        if (vehicleManagedObjectContext == nil) {
            NSLog(@"======== Error: vehicleManagedObjectContext is empty"); 
        }

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"VehicleInfo" inManagedObjectContext:vehicleManagedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"vehicleType" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:vehicleManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"vehicleType" cacheName:nil];

        [fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];

        NSLog(@"======== fetchedObjects : %@",[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]);

        if ([fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] && [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] > 0) {
            return [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
        }

        return nil;
    }
```

Comment: I've edited your post to make it more readable and only showing the essentials